# OpenCV build support for Windows 8 ARM

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

Has anyone succeeded in building OpenCV for ARM on Windows 8?

I am specifically interested in using OpenCV in Windows 8 apps for tablets.

This guy shows some face detection using OpenCV for Windows 8.  But I think it's on x86:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV322

Comment: I am about to start a project where i would like to use the matrix operations from OpenCV in a windows 8. I assume it will involve getting OpenCV or parts of compiled for Windows RT. I will post any findings i find here. (My project spans over the next 6 weeks.).

Comment: Dont see it happening before cmake releases a new version. And then there is also all the API calls in OpenCV that are not allowed on WinRT.